# Can't run projects in Codelite

Tags: hard-drive, c++

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10. I'm now trying to use CodeLite to code C++, but when I create a project in my hard drive partitions I can't run it. It says `no such file or directory`, but it runs normally if I create it in Documents (root).

```
/home/hussein/.codelite/tmp/hussein/codelite-exec.sh: line 3: /media/hussein/F2B288F7B288C199/c++: No such file or directory
Hit any key to continue...
```

[image: screenshot of terminal]

This is the build log:

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j8 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ okashat - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/hussein/F2B288F7B288C199/c++ course/Section14/okashat'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/hussein/F2B288F7B288C199/c++ course/Section14/okashat'
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, rather copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

this problem i have encountered it due to 2 reasons , the first one is that i didn't disable **the fast start up** from windows "i had installed Ubuntu along side with windows " so i recommend that you do that . the second reason is that may be the the problem is with genome terminal so if you go to **settings->preferences -> terminal -> codelite-terminal** this solved the problem for me, also before running the project on codelite it's highly recommended to go to **build->clean project**

Answer (score 1):

As the error message was really generic, everyone would come up with his own story.

As for me, it had something to do with a misconfigured compiler's options at the project's global settings.

Answer (score 0):

System: MacOS (Apple silicon)
I had this issue as well. For me it was a incorrect compiler configuration.

To choose the correct option to be able to build/run a project:
Right-click project -> *Settings* -> *General* -> *Build (cell)* -> Select

See my attached image for details of my configuration

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>